# why ajax error apper before controller executing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax plugin

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.Ajax_Data = function (Controller, Action, Data, onsuccess, onerror) {
    event.preventDefault();

        var options = {};
        options.url = "/" + Controller + "/" + Action;
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify(Data);
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = onsuccess;
        options.eerror = onerror;

        $.ajax(options);
};
})(jQuery);
```

I have this controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void Delete(int Id)
{
     Employee Emp = DBCon.Employees.Single(a => a.Emp_ID == Id);
     DBCon.Employees.Remove(Emp);
     DBCon.SaveChanges();
}
```

And finally i can call ajax plugin to invoke controller method like this

```
$(this).Ajax_Data("OnePageGrid", "Delete", { Id: 1},
{ onsuccess: document.getElementById("tblBlah").deleteRow(1) },
{ onerror: alert('There is something wrong !!') });
```

the known lifecycle is
1 - execute ajax plugin
2 - invoke controller method
3 - if there is something wrong ajax error message will appear

but i have problem here that's 
when i call ajax plugin the error message appear before controller executing
proof that : the error alert is appearing then the tracer on the controller working after that

please if any one know the reason or solution for this issue help me

Comment: `options.eerror` - double e?

Comment: yes brother I changed it but the problem steal appear

Comment: you are calling `event.preventDefault();` in plugin but there is no event and `event` variable is undefined. Should be specific about what errros are thrown and from what part of the code. Also your arguments for `onsuccess` and `onerror` should be in functions. This whole plugin makes very little sense as a `$.fn` plugin

Comment: Also you callbacks do not look right. Should be `onerror: function() { alert('There is something wrong !!'); }` and same for success

Comment: and what is `this` when you call the plugin?

Comment: very thank for you it's realy fix my problem